# Dependency error while installing MariaDB on Amazon Linux AMI CentOS 7

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, mariadb, centos7

Below is the error when I try installing MariaDB on CentOS 7 (an Amazon AMI)

```
[root@hostname ~]# yum install MariaDB-server
Loaded plugins: update-motd, upgrade-helper
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:10.2.7-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: MariaDB-client for package: MariaDB-server-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DBI) for package: MariaDB-server-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: galera for package: MariaDB-server-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: MariaDB-common for package: MariaDB-server-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Data::Dumper) for package: MariaDB-server-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-client.x86_64 0:10.2.7-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-client-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package MariaDB-common.x86_64 0:10.2.7-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: MariaDB-compat for package: MariaDB-common-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:10.2.7-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package galera.x86_64 0:25.3.20-1.rhel7.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_program_options.so.1.53.0()(64bit) for package: galera-25.3.20-1.rhel7.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package perl-DBI.x86_64 0:1.627-4.8.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(RPC::PlClient) >= 0.2000 for package: perl-DBI-1.627-4.8.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(RPC::PlServer) >= 0.2001 for package: perl-DBI-1.627-4.8.amzn1.x86_64
---> Package perl-Data-Dumper.x86_64 0:2.145-3.5.amzn1 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-client.x86_64 0:10.2.7-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-client-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package MariaDB-compat.x86_64 0:10.2.7-1.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:10.2.7-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package boost-program-options.x86_64 0:1.53.0-14.21.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package perl-PlRPC.noarch 0:0.2020-14.7.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Net::Daemon) >= 0.13 for package: perl-PlRPC-0.2020-14.7.amzn1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Compress::Zlib) for package: perl-PlRPC-0.2020-14.7.amzn1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Net::Daemon::Test) for package: perl-PlRPC-0.2020-14.7.amzn1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Net::Daemon::Log) for package: perl-PlRPC-0.2020-14.7.amzn1.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-client.x86_64 0:10.2.7-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-client-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:10.2.7-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package perl-IO-Compress.noarch 0:2.061-2.12.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Compress::Raw::Zlib) >= 2.061 for package: perl-IO-Compress-2.061-2.12.amzn1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Compress::Raw::Bzip2) >= 2.061 for package: perl-IO-Compress-2.061-2.12.amzn1.noarch
---> Package perl-Net-Daemon.noarch 0:0.48-5.5.amzn1 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-client.x86_64 0:10.2.7-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-client-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:10.2.7-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package perl-Compress-Raw-Bzip2.x86_64 0:2.061-3.11.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib.x86_64 1:2.061-4.1.amzn1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: MariaDB-client-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (mariadb)
           Requires: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: MariaDB-server-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (mariadb)
           Requires: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit)
Error: Package: MariaDB-server-10.2.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (mariadb)
           Requires: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Below is the repo details**strong text**

```
[root@hostname ~]# yum repolist enabled | grep MariaDB

mariadb                               MariaDB                                18
```

How to resolve this dependency?

Comment: There are wonderful docker images of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
yum clean all
```

and

```
yum update
```